# QuickFixCmdPost autocommand after Glog

Tags: autocmd, quickfix, plugin-fugitive

I run `Glog!` from `fugitive` to populate the quickfix window and set the following autocmd for `QuickFixCmdPost` (The following questions general and are not specific to `Glog`, I just use it as example)

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * call func()

function func()
    echomsg 'quickfix: ' . w:quickfix_title
    botright cwindow
    if w:quickfix_title =~ 'git.*log'
        nnoremap <buffer> v <c-w><cr><C-w>L
    endif
endfunction
```

According to doc (`:h w:quickfix_title`) `w:quickfix_title` is supposed to contain the command used, which is something like `:git --git-dir=.git --no-pager log --no-color` set by `fugitive`.

However, after running `Glog`, the `func()` is called and `w:quickfix_title` is always empty. But the quickfix window's statusline still displays the title correctly.

What is the problem here? It seems that `w:quickfix_title` is not set before the autocmd finishes. Calling `:cwindow` to open the window does not get it set immediately.

**A few more questions:**

- Accoring to `:h QuickFixCmdPre`, the pattern is matched against the command being run, such as `:grep`, `:lgrep`, etc. If I run `:grep abcdefg`, is that `abcdefg` part of the command and can be used as pattern? If yes, I know that `Glog` contains `git.*log` in its command, can I use this as the pattern instead of putting the `if` condition in `func`, i.e.

  `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost git*log call func()`
- If before running `Glog` the quickfix window is not open, the following autocmds are not triggered (even if I call `cwindow` explicitly in `func`):

  - `BufEnter`
  - `WinEnter`
  - `BufWinEnter`

  However, if the quickfix window is already open, `BufWinEnter` is trigged. What is the reason for this?
- What is the correct way to set up some maps in quickfix window after `Glog` is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this solution: that is to check the `&grepprg`, which is a string. For `Glog`, it should match `^git\>.*\<grep\>`. (has exceptions since `grep` may appear as filename)

The function will look like

```
function func()
    if &grepprg =~ 'git.*log'
        nnoremap <buffer> v <c-w><cr><C-w>L
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

`w:quickfix_title` is a window-local variable (`w:` part). This means `w:quickfix_title` will only available after the quickfix window is opened and is focused. This means `echomsg w:quickfix_title` will not show the quickfix title reliably.

However your first method should work. I checked it and it worked for me after adjusting your function name. You can check for your mapping via `nnmap v` while you are in the quickfix window.

This sort of works however once the mapping is created then it is not properly cleared if the quickfix list changes. It would be better to always have a quickfix window mapping and have a conditional on the mapping itself.

```
augroup My_qf
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <expr> <buffer> v getqflist({'title':1}).title =~ 'git.*log' ? \"<c-w>\<cr>\<c-w>L" : "v"
augroup END
```

You may decide every quickfix window should have this mapping for consistency then the conditional would not be needed so you would end up with:

```
augroup My_qf
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType qf nnoremap  <buffer> v <c-w>\<cr>\<c-w>L
augroup END
```

For more help see:

```
:h QuickFixCmdPost
:h CTRL-W_<Enter>
:h getqflist()
:h w:
:h w:quickfix_title
:h :map-expression
```

Comment: as you said: "w:quickfix_title is a window-local variable (w: part). This means w:quickfix_title will only available after the quickfix window is opened and is focused". But In `func()`, `cwindow` is explicitly called, Isn't that enough to have `w:quickfix_title` set?

Comment: for your suggestion of using `autocmd BufWinEnter quickfix if (w:quickfix_title =~ 'git.*log') | nnoremap <buffer> v <c-w><cr><C-w>L | endif`, I already said that `BufWinEnter` is not triggered by `Glog` if the quickfix window is not open before running `Glog`

Comment: @LiuSha, You are correct, `w:quickfix_title` should be set (I have updated my post). You are also correct `BufWinEnter` is triggered "after a buffer is displayed in a window", so this technique should be avoided and I have removed it from the post. You maybe able to `WinEnter` instead, but I have not tested it.